# Access to screen buffer of a console application from another application (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot, windows-console

I need access to the screen buffer of a console application run from cmd.exe in Windows 7. I made an application in C# which is accessing the console window via `SendInput` (take screenshot of console application to clipboard via Alt+Space, Edit/Select all, Enter). `SendInput` works, but it is not a clear solution. Direct access to the screen of the console would be better. How can I read the screen of a console application from another application (C#)?

Comment: videoram != console. are you talking about the, typically, 80 characters wide text screen, or a legacy DOS application running in a DOS compatibility sandbox with a graphical user interface?

Comment: Yes, I mean screen with matrix 80x25 of chars of DOS application runnig under cmd.exe.

Comment: I've never attempted reading from another process' console, therefore this is just a comment, but it looks like when you attach to the console of another process using the `AttachConsole` Windows API function, while sharing you can also access the contents of that console: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole

Comment: I found GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo (https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getconsolescreenbufferinfo). It returns only description about screen, no data...

Comment: I'm removing the DOS tag because you almost certainly mean a Windows console application. There is some confusion here because Windows 9x used the 16-bit DOS COMMAND.COM shell and utilities, whereas Windows NT uses WinAPI console applications such as cmd.exe. NT took over as the only supported implementation starting with Windows XP. 32-bit versions of NT include a virtual DOS machine, but this feature was never released for 64-bit Windows. So chances are that your system can't even execute a DOS program without installing an emulator.

Comment: FYI, cmd.exe is just like any other console application. Any Windows application can attach to a console host (conhost.exe), which hosts the console window and input/screen buffers. In Windows 7 this connection uses an LPC port and shared memory. In Windows 8+ it uses files on the ConDrv device (e.g. minimally a Connect handle -- and possibly also files for console I/O buffers). Your goal in general is to detach from the current console (if any) via `FreeConsole`; attach to the console of the target process via `AttachConsole`; open the screen (CONOUT$), and read it via `ReadConsoleOutput`.